# Can't impersonate on a service-to-service oauth request to google calendar api in ruby

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

Hi I was late night hacking and testing google api client for Ruby.

I fell in an error perhaps by missunderstanding.

**What I already done**

- I already created an app in google developer console
- I enabled the calendar api
- I created the Server Key and downloaded the p12.
- I managed to see that calendar metadata using the google api explorer and browser oauth, so the ids are confirmed and the permissions too as browser's oauth can view the metadata

**What I'm triying to do:**

I'm triying to get metadata (I will try events later) from a privately shared calendar where I have read permissions (trough a group) in a google apps for work account in Ruby on a service to service auth

**How I'm triying to do it**

With this code:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'pp'
client = Google::APIClient.new

cal = client.discovered_api('calendar','v3')

id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com'  # id is the confirmed calendar ID

key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('sl.p12', 'notasecret')
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  :issuer => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',  # confirmed issuer

  :signing_key => key
)

client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

result = client.execute(
  :api_method => cal.calendars.get,  
  :parameters => { 'calendarId' => id }  
)

puts result.response.body

pp result
```

Results colected

When I do this y get a 404, something like "that calendar does not exists"

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "Not Found"
      }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

But if i change id per 'primary'

I get:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"dAAhx6wYoPw2vqRAe54lk5wa0XQ/WEglF6_c5pVHKyggcENvvX1cS9g\"",
 "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",    #same as issuer id ??? WTF
 "summary": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
 "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

Which seems to be a calendar but it's like the default calendar for the "email issuer" account that appears in the server key "email" field

I also tried to ad a `:person = 'email'` field to `client.authorization` but then I get an error creating the auth token

I couldn't find a way to access the api as other mail account dirrerent from that @developer.gserviceaccount.com, so what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can either share the calendar with the service account's email or follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) to allow the service account to impersonate any user on that domain, in which case you have to pass the `:person => 'email'` parameter.